# How to get the first object in an JSONObject without knowing the name?

Tags: java, android

I've a `JSONObject` that contains other objects:

```
{
"1" : {
        "state": [],
        "hue": 224
      }
"2" : {
        "state": [],
        "hue": 224
      }
"3" : {
        "state": [],
        "hue": 224
      }
}
```

It's the response from the Philips Hue Brigde JSON that contains all the connected lights. I use Volley for the http connection.
I created a Light class where I store the data like state, hue, bri etc. I fill the Light class by using of a for loop in the onResponse from Volley:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= response.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject lightObject = response.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i)); 
     System.out.println("OBJECT " + lightObject);

     // Use try/catch because of empty or unknown key
                try {
                    description = lightObject.getString("type");
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                try {
                    bri = lightObjectState.getInt("bri");
                } catch (Exception e) {}

                try {
                    sat = lightObjectState.getInt("sat");
                } catch (Exception e) {}

                try {
                    hue = lightObjectState.getInt("hue");
                } catch (Exception e) {}

     Light light = new Light(String.valueOf(i),lightObject.getString("name"), description, on, bri, sat, hue);
     mLightList.add(light);
     mLightAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

The problem with the for loop is that, when the Light id starts with greater then zero, it will crash my Android app, because there is `no value of 0`.
My question is how I can get the first object of the response without knowing the `key` name that contains the object with all the properties of one light, so when the `JSONObject` looks like below, the app will not crash, but just display light 4 till 6:

```
{
"4" : {
        "state": [],
        "hue": 224
      }
"5" : {
        "state": [],
        "hue": 224
      }
"6" : {
        "state": [],
        "hue": 224
      }
}
```

If there are any questions left, please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Iterator<?> iterate=obj.keys();

Comment: how many lights are there ?

Comment: use JSONArray insted of JSONObject as main then you can get it by iterator

Comment: But it starts with the curly braces `{}` then you haven't an array right? @RajeshKushvaha

Comment: @Caspert yes, make it's array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    // use keys() iterator, you don't need to know what keys are there/missing
    Iterator<String> iter = response.keys();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = iter.next();
        JSONObject lightObject = response.getJSONObject(key); 
        System.out.println("key: " + key + ", OBJECT " + lightObject);

        // you can check if the object has a key before you access it
        if (lightObject.has("bri")) {
            bri = lightObject.getInt("bri");
        }

        if (lightObject.has("sat")) {
            sat = lightObject.getInt("sat");
        }

        if (lightObject.has("hue")) {
            hue = lightObject.getInt("hue");
        }

        if (lightObject.has("name")) {
            name = lightObject.getString("name")
        }

        Light light = new Light(key, name, description, on, bri, sat, hue);
        mLightList.add(light);
    }

    mLightAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hmm, get an error: `android foreach not applicable to type java.util.iterator`. at response.keys()

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Kris, really thankful! It is working great.

Answer (score 2):

try with object key:

```
 Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
 if( keys.hasNext() ){
     String key = (String)keys.next(); // First key in your json object
  }
```

Comment: i have made changes

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a class called Bulb

```
public class Bulb {

    int[] state;
    int hue;

}
```

Then you can use a JSON serializer like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

And then you can map your response to in a Map ( like HashMap ) like this

```
Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, Bulb>>() { }.getType();

Map<String,Bulb> bulbMap = gson.fromJson(json, typeOfHashMap);
```

And then you can iterate over the map with keys like so

```
Iterator bulbIterator = bulbMap.entrySet().iterator();

  while (bulbIterator.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)bulbIterator.next();

    String pKey = (String) pair.getKey();

    Bulb bulb = (Bulb) pair.getValue();

    // Do something here with the bulb
}
```